# Open PDF files in Firefox or Chrome with Acrobat Reader DC via playonlinux

Tags: firefox, chrome, playonlinux, acrobat-reader

I'm a professional typesetter and I really need to use `Acrobat Reader DC` on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I installed it via `playonlinux`. I call it by command line with:

```
playonlinux --run Adobe\ Acrobat\ Reader\ DC mypdffile.pdf
```

My question is: can I make `Mozilla Firefox` or `Google Chrome` open a pdf file with `Acrobat Reader` installed via `playonlinux`? On `Firefox` I can choose a default reader but I'm not able to see `Acrobat Reader` in my options.

(I know I can download the pdf file and open it with the reader... but this is very annoying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (actually a friend of mine solved it) by creating a script (I named it AcrobatDC):

```
#!/bin/bash
playonlinux --run "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" $1
```

Then I told Firefox to open PDF files with my script in Firefox's `preferences`:

[image]